# Approximating P(A,B,C) using P(A,B), P(A,C), P(B,C), and P(A), P(B), P(C)

Tags: probability, approximation

For some events $A$, $B$, $C$ 
I know the occurrence probabilities $P(A),\:  P(B),\: P(C)$ 
I also know the pairwise co-occurance probabilities $P(A,B),\: P(A,C),\: P(B,C)$

**I want to approximate the triple co-occurance probability: $P(A,B,C)$
By making some (incorrect) assumptions** (eg about independence.)

I know that if I assume all events are mutually  independent then I can make the approximation: $P(A,B,C)\approxeq P(A)\;P(B)\;P(C)$

But I have more information than just the individual marginal probability since I also have the pairwise information, which is not used in the approximation above. So a better estimate should be possible

Comment: Do you know the probability$P(A\cup B\cup C)$? then you can exactly calculate the $P(A\cap B \cap C)$

Comment: No. I only know pairwise statistics.

Answer (score 2):

### Bounding

$$
P(A \cup B \cup C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(A \cap B) - P(B \cap C) - P(C \cap A) + P(A \cap B \cap C) 
$$
$\implies$

$$
P(A \cap B \cap C)  = P(A \cup B \cup C) - \big(P(A) + P(B) + P(C)\big) + \big(P(A \cap B) + P(B \cap C) + P(C \cap A)\big)
$$

and

$$ 0 \leq P(A \cup B \cup C) \leq 1$$

$\implies$
$$
 - \big(P(A) + P(B) + P(C)\big) + \big(P(A \cap B) + P(B \cap C) + P(C \cap A)\big) \leq P(A \cap B \cap C) \leq 1- \big(P(A) + P(B) + P(C)\big) + \big(P(A \cap B) + P(B \cap C) + P(C \cap A)\big)
$$

### Approximating

$$
\begin{align}
P(A \cap B \cap C) &= P\big((A \cap B) \cap C\big)\\
&= P(C|(A \cap B))P(A \cap B) \tag{1}\\
&or\ P(B|(A \cap C))P(A \cap C) \tag{2}\\
&or\ P(A|(B \cap C))P(B \cap C) \tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Which assuming conditional independence is respectively equal to:

$$
\begin{align}
P(A \cap B \cap C) 
&= P(C)P(A \cap B) \tag{1a}\\
&or\  P(B)P(A \cap C) \tag{2a}\\
&or\  P(A)P(B \cap C) \tag{3a}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks. Still reading over this a few times, but 
I don't understand the part of your answer below "Approximating". 1) What is "*or*" 2) How is $P(C|(A \cup B)$ calculated from only the pairwise/individual probabilities?

Comment: Ahh I see how 2) works it $P(C|(A \cup B)=P(C)$ if $C$ is conditional independent of $A\capB$
And 1.) the "*or*" is depending on which I dependancy I take.

Could I take the average of the 3 ors to get a better approximation?

Comment: @rightskewed are you approximating the value if you give three possibilities? I think that you would want to aggregate these three values in some way based on the underlying problem. As Oxinabox suggests, this could be an average, but if this is in some application, then you might rather want to go for the $\min$ or the $\max$.

Comment: I can't think of a strict inequality right now that will motivate the use of $max$ or $min$